# undefined symbol: _gst_fraction_type for gstreamer 1.*

Tags: linux, gcc, gstreamer

I am using gstreamer1.* for playback. But I am getting the undefined symbol error for _gst_fraction_type at runtime.

I have installed all the required packages/gstreamer plugings.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this symbol is there for you in a first place (maybe too old gstreamer). The responsible library is called `libgstriff-1.0.so`.

```
nm -g libgstriff-1.0.so  | grep _gst_fraction_type
```

If you cant find it you can use:

```
locate libgstriff-1.0.so
```

I guess your app picked wrong gstreamer (probably older system gstreamer).

You can check:

```
ldd ./yourapp | grep libgstriff
```

I am not sure if this library is dynamicly loaded in that case this will show you more:

```
strace ./yourapp 2>&1 | grep libgstriff
```

Then check the path which is used for this file.

In case this does not help please provide more info and I will update:

- what OS you use?
- what gstreamer version are you running and how did you installed them?
- how do you compile (what gcc arguments etc?) and run your app ?
- are you able to run simple pipeline `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink` ?

I started with [this post](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Raspberry-Pi-libgstriff-1-0-so-0-undefined-symbol-gst-fraction-type-td4667756.html) which may be helpful to you..

HTH